# Using Material UI Tabs with React Router, set the selected tab?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-router, react-router-dom

Working with React, Material-UI, and React-Router, and I am trying to use React-Router in conjunction with Material-UI tabs. In fact I have it all working, but with one caveat. If a user uses a route to load a specific page, the `Tabs` does not show the correct tab as selected. It all works once the user is in the app; they can click tabs and the app does all three things correctly (loads the correct page, shows the correct tab selected, shows the correct URL and path), but if they type in a path directly into their browser the first tab is selected.

App:

```
function App() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState("1");
  const handleChange = (e: React.SyntheticEvent, newPage: string) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header title="My Site" />
        <TabContext value={page}>
          <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
            <Tabs
              aria-label="Tab navigation"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={page}
              variant="fullWidth"
            >
              <Tab label="Tab One" component={Link} to="/pageOne" value="1" />
              <Tab label="Tab Two" component={Link} to="/pageTwo" value="2" />
              <Tab label="Tab Three" component={Link} to="/pageThree" value="3" />
              <Tab label="Tab Four" component={Link} to="/pageFour" value="4" />
            </Tabs>
          </Box>
        </TabContext>
        <Footer />

        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<pageOne />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/pageOne"
            element={<pageOne />}
          />
          <Route path="/pageTwo" element={<pageTwo />} />
          <Route path="/pageThree" element={<pageThree />} />
          <Route path="/pageFour" element={<pageFour />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This all works as expected, since the initial `page` state defaults to `"1"`. That state variable `page` is a holdover from when I just had tabs and not `react-router`; I am not sure if I need to get rid of that.

I've been trying to figure out how to determine what that value should be based on the entered path, but parsing the `window.location.href` string and setting the default to `{[conditional goes here]}` is not working: I get an error from React telling me that a condition like `pageString === "pageTwo"` will always return false, since JS is comparing references and not values.

Currently using `react@18.2.0`, `mui@5.12.3`, and `react-router-dom@6.11.0`.

Comment: Well, of course now that I've posted I tried again with parsing "window.location.href"...and this time it worked. So I do have it running.

That being said, that feels like a kludgy (and not scalable) solution. Is there a more elegant one? I thought of using something like useEffects, but this isn't an issue with state changes, just initial load...and I don't know if there would be any other method besides at some point doing all the parsing. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the URL path as the source of truth for which tab should be active/selected. In other words, ***don't*** duplicate the "tab state" when you can let `react-router-dom` manage the "state". When the `App` component renders, for any reason, the active/selected tab will *automagically* be synchronized to the current route path value.

Use the `useLocation` hook to access the current `pathname` value and pass this as the `Tabs` component's `value` prop value, and update all the `Tab` components to use a path value instead of the string values `"1"` through `"4"`. The `Router` will need to be promoted higher in the ReactTree so that `App` can use the `useLocation` hook.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header title="My Site" />
      <TabContext value={pathname}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
          <Tabs
            aria-label="Tab navigation"
            value={pathname}
            variant="fullWidth"
          >
            <Tab label="Tab One" component={Link} to="/pageOne" value="/pageOne" />
            <Tab label="Tab Two" component={Link} to="/pageTwo" value="/pageTwo" />
            <Tab label="Tab Three" component={Link} to="/pageThree" value="/pageThree" />
            <Tab label="Tab Four" component={Link} to="/pageFour" value="/pageFour" />
          </Tabs>
        </Box>
      </TabContext>
      <Footer />

      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Navigate to="/pageOne" />} />
        <Route path="/pageOne" element={<PageOne />} />
        <Route path="/pageTwo" element={<PageTwo />} />
        <Route path="/pageThree" element={<PageThree />} />
        <Route path="/pageFour" element={<PageFour />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

...

<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit using-material-ui-tabs-with-react-router-set-the-selected-tab]